# [].every((i) => i === 5) results in true in javascript, How?

Tags: javascript

I was going through Instagram and saw this one, I thought it would result in false but, when I ran it, I got true!

```
[].every((i) => i === 5)
```

Why?

Comment: I don't think the `every` loop even runs.

Comment: Because every item in the array is 5. Every single one. All zero of them.